# when to use domain event?

Tags: concurrency, domain-driven-design, aggregate, domain-events

In DDD, I'm wondering when should I use domain event? Is there any recommendation of situations suitable for using domain event? Is it only for case where eventually consistent is acceptable?

Let's say in a online store example with Product, Order, OrderLine, one Order contains multiple OrderLine. One OrderLine has 1-to-1 relationship with Product, when I create an order, at the same time, I need to deduct the amount available in Product. There are 2 ways that I know:

1. In OrderService (application service):

   - create a new Order, insert into database
   - for each order line in Order, get Product associated with that OrderLine, call Product.UpdateQuantity()
   - save all products to database
   - Note: to me, seem like application service does most of the work here (create order, get product, update product), is it acceptable?
2. In OrderService:

   - create a new Order, insert into database
   - generate an event OrderCreated
   - an event handler trigged, call Product.UpdateQuantity()
   - Note: The product quantity is not guaranteed to be updated immediately

In real life, which way is more preferred?
And in both cases, how to handle concurrency update to product quantity? Notify user of failure if number of quantity is not the same as the time user see checkout screen?

Many thanks

Comment: Do "real life" and DDD belong in the same sentence?  I loved that book when I read it, but it feels like one of those ideas that's been passed by.

Comment: haha, I don't have chance to see a real life DDD application before, so I can't say whether they are mutually exclusive, but even if it's not, I think have many concepts that I can learn from that

Answer (score 1):

I think your decision needs to revolve around units of work and ACID.

If this service owns the database and represents the only interface through which users access this information, then the method needs to be a single unit of work that's managed as one transaction by the service.

I don't understand the difference between the two examples you provided.

When I order things on Amazon, I expect to see my product quantities for my order to be updated immediately and be consistent with what I put it.  I have no idea if their inventory system "catches up later" or if it becomes part of my transaction.  I wouldn't want my order to fail because their inventory system had a problem.  I could see where they might have some mechanism that made my order persistent and durable and let the inventory system catch up later (perhaps a queue).  But that's a detail that the service may not need to know about.